# Model of Coq (pCuIC) in higher toposes?

Tags: type-theory, coq, homotopy-type-theory

Can the type theory of Coq (pCuIC) be modeled in all higher Grothendieck toposes?
First of all, even the [set theoretical model](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01952037/document) is not complete (e.g. inductive types in Prop). Although, this is expected to work.
[Shulman](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.07004) has shown that type theory with W-types can be interpreted in higher Grothendieck toposes. [Inductive families](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/inductive+family) can be reduced to W-types. These are claimed to be similar to the inductive families of Coq. However, I am not sure I’ve ever seen a precise result along these lines.
[Voevodsky](https://www.math.ias.edu/~vladimir/Site3/Univalent_Foundations_files/expressions_current.pdf) has made a similar reduction for Coq’s inductive types, but I am not sure it’s entirely up to date, or complete. The note was never published. Moreover, it was written before pCuIC came out.
Finally, Coq also has co-inductive types. Again, [M-types](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/M-type) can be interpreted in HoTT, but I am not aware of a reduction of Coq's co-inductive types to M-types.

Comment: I guess pCuIC as in [Consistency of the Predicative Calculus of Cumulative Inductive Constructions (pCuIC)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.03912)?

Comment: Ah, I see that looks to be a different version of the same paper.